# Pre and Post test statistical analysis of 2 groups

Tags: correlation

For my research I will be looking at pre and post intervention scores of 2 groups, 1 group children 1 group primary caregivers. I want to see if there is a difference in scores pre and post for both groups individually but also if any change in children scores can be correlated to primary caregiver scores. Any suggestions on statistical analysis would be welcome!

Comment: Assuming it is the same children and care givers pre and post, you will presumably want to look at individual changes rather than group changes.  For your secondary analysis, the analysis may be affected by whether there is a 1-1 relationship between children and their caregivers, and whether you think that changes to children may be affected by changes to care givers or the other way round

Comment: Are the children linked with primary caregiver in the data, i.e., do you have pairs of pairs of data (first pair = repeated measurements)?

Comment: Yes the children are linked to primary care givers- they are the same group of children with their primary caregivers, the expectation is that an improvement in child score will positively effect primary caregivers scores

Comment: Agreed with [Scar_Face](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/343223/scar-face)’s response. A mixed two-way ANOVA seems appropriate here. You might also consider using linear mixed models as an alternative. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00002/full

Comment: Thank you giopic and Scar_Face that's very helpful 

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the means of more than two groups (e.g. the average heights of children, teenagers, and adults) you can use ANOVA and MANOVA.
If you want to examine between same class you can use paired t-test.

Another method(for dynamic case) you can follow is to try simple spearman's correlation test for each iteration and create a subsidiary dataset from it and then try regression analysis on it.

Pardon me, if my answer was not up to your expectation.